# How to open a dialog on the click of any folder in sdcard in android

Tags: android

I have an interesting problem that I want to secure our particular folder of sdcard with a password means I want to open a dialog when user click on the same and user enter his credential and if the credentials are right then user can see their files otherwise not. Same as Hide it Pro app does. Can you suggest me how can it be possible?

**Edit:**
Can any one tell that How the Hiding apps are working or we can say that what is the mechanism behind hiding or securing the files/folders in Android device.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean protecting it in _any_ file browser or just in one you developed?

Comment: Yes stefan, in any file browser

Comment: YOu can't. Becoz what about if user mounted that sdcard on the system?

Comment: i highly doubt it's possible. at least I expect it's not possible without root access

Comment: you have to do crypto or somebody pulls the card and there go your files

Comment: @stefan - what about when we mounted sdcard on system and open that folder? will it open? or it display dialog at their?

Comment: depends on the method. if the file/folder is encrypted it will not open anywhere without a software. if permissions of that file/folder are modified it's still possible for root users on any device/system to open these files. the dialog - if possible to create one - will only appear if the app is installed, hence not on any other system.

Comment: @stefan - exactly, that's the problem, to prevent this from other user in their system the folder is encrypted.

Comment: @user370305: that doesn't solve the problem displaying a dialog at all, because the app has to intercept if another app wants to enter the folder. this seems impossible..

Comment: @stefan -  I don't tell this, the problem is solved, I say we can't achieve this easily, at any time if our app is running or not, if anybody access the folder the dialog box is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**android point of view.**
1) There is no particular Intent broadcasted when you access to a file/fodler
2) by default "File access" is made by an application provided by the manufacturer and is not part of android core application (not existing in SDK emulator)

**Application point of view**
Without talking about encryption but protected access, you've to design  your own File access application and be able to disable any other existing system file access application..I guess this is not a easy way.(is it do-able ?)

Or you design an app that access custom archive file (with or without protection by encryption or other means), that file is showed as a complete file system by your app.
Some similarities with a MS windows "compressed file folder" that is in reality a Zip file
Your app manage the GoIn/GoOut file from/to the protected "special archive"..

Then by managing your own archive file type, it is inherently protected from access by other application.

Hope that help.